# Troubles with reading text file after Build

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, executable, streamreader

I'm having trouble reading a text file in Unity3D.
I've created a method which returns a type float[][] and takes a streamreader as argument:

```
public float[][] CreateWeights(StreamReader reader){
    int n = 0;
    float[][] Weights = new float[50][];

    while((!reader.EndOfStream)){
        string text = reader.ReadLine();
            if (text == null)
            break;

        string[] strFloats = text.Split (new char[0]);
        float[] floats = new float[strFloats.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i<strFloats.Length; i++){
            floats[i] = float.Parse(strFloats[i]);

        }
        Weights[n] = floats;
        n++;
    }
    return Weights;
}
```

I make use of this method in void Start() to create "weights":

```
float[][] WeightsIH; 
float[][] WeightsHO;

void Start(){

    FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/WeightsIH.txt");
    StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();

    FileInfo theSourceFile2 = new FileInfo(Application.dataPath + "/Resources/WeightsHO.txt");
    StreamReader reader2 = theSourceFile2.OpenText();

    WeightsIH = CreateWeights(reader);
    WeightsHO = CreateWeights(reader2);

    Yhidden = new float[50][];
    HiddenOutput = new float[50][];
    Xoutput = new float[1];

}
```

And this will work fine in Unity's play mode. However, after creating an executable, the files won't be found, which I do understand. So to make it work, I understood that I need to use Resources.Load and I have:

```
void Start(){

    TextAsset text1 = Resources.Load("WeightsIH") as TextAsset;
    TextAsset text2 = Resources.Load("WeightsHO") as TextAsset;

    WeightsIH = CreateWeights(text1);
    WeightsHO = CreateWeights(text2);

    Yhidden = new float[50][];
    HiddenOutput = new float[50][];
    Xoutput = new float[1];

}
```

Of course the argument type can't be a streamReader anymore, and I changed it to take TextAsset as argument. Here's how it changed:

```
public float[][] CreateWeights(TextAsset textAsset){

    float[][] Weights = new float[50][];

    string[] linesFromFile = textAsset.text.Split("\n"[0]);

    for(int i = 0; i<linesFromFile.Length; i++){

        string[] strFloats = linesFromFile[i].Split (new char[0]);
        float[] floats = new float[strFloats.Length];
        for(int j = 0; j<strFloats.Length; j++){
            floats[j] = float.Parse(strFloats[j]);

        }
        Weights[i] = floats;

    }
    return Weights;
}
```

Now this won't work **at all**, not even in play mode. The run-time error I would get is as follows:

> FormatException: Invalid format.
>
> System.Double.Parse (System.String s, NumberStyles style,
>   IFormatProvider provider) (
>  at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Double.cs:209)
>   System.Single.Parse (System.String s) (
>  at
>   /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System/Single.cs:183)
>   FollowShortestPath.CreateWeights (UnityEngine.TextAsset textAsset)
>   (
>  at Assets/Scripts/Pathfinding/FollowShortestPath.cs:203)
>   FollowShortestPath.Start () (
>  at
>   Assets/Scripts/Pathfinding/FollowShortestPath.cs:54)

line 54 refers to:

```
WeightsIH = CreateWeights(text1);
```

and line 203 refers to:

```
floats[j] = float.Parse(strFloats[j]);
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I get the text files to be read successfully in in the executable?

Comment: As you can see, I removed my answer. But can you show the text files you are loading and parsing?

Comment: sure: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9jfat0x7a6m39n6/AADHLj9TatRbD_MmMpq8Yl2pa?dl=0)

Comment: Okay I found it. Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is with text file format you are loading.

Couse you have many white spaces

```
string[] strFloats = text.Split (new char[0]);
```

will result in that some strings are empty.

To fix this, remove extra withe spaces from text files or use:

```
for(int j = 0; j<strFloats.Length; j++){
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty (strFloats [j]))
                continue;

            floats[j] = float.Parse(strFloats[j]);

        }
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Like I said:I understand that in the executable Application.dataPath won't work. That's why I changed it to Resources.Load . But then again, is this the correct approach? And if so, what am I doing wrongly in my altered piece of code? The way I see it, it should return the same result..

Comment: I see, sorry to not answer directly. Let me try it and if I cannot find answer I will delete this one.

Comment: I think I found the problem.

Comment: Excuse my mistake, but the code was originally without the .txt extension, and then it would give the error. I accidentally copied the code after having experimented lately. I changed the original post. Also, i tried typecasting like this:WeightsH = CreateWeights((TextAsset)text1); etc.. But as expected, this doesn't change anything.

Comment: I see, then I will delete this answer as I cant find anything. Sorry.

Comment: Thank You! Sorry for answering so late, I was testing the builds on different machines. And everything works fine now! Your answer is accepted